# Is "angried" synonymous with "angry"?

Tags: synonyms

One of my friends asked me whether "angried" can be used in place of "angry" or not. It led me to a google search, and I got  **[these results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22angried%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)** to my surprise. It is for the first time that I come across such a usage as:

> *Then, reconsidering, she added, "No, actually I'm angried."* -
>   "Angried?" "Whatever for?"

Can we use "angried" in place of "angry"? Is it a standard and acceptable usage?

Comment: To me it seems like an alternative spelling of "angered" -- i.e. when something has made you angry. As such it seems slightly different from "angry" which is what you are when something has angered you.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at [ngrams: angried](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=angried&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=1) it seems to have been most popular in the early 1800's and largely non-existent in the last century.

Looking at [results for those years](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22angried%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1729,cd_max:1840&lr=lang_en) when it was slightly more popular, we find usages such as

- "[..] but Ahab had angried God"
- "Our temperate Sage, though angried at that spirit of contradiction [..]"
- "[..] seemed very sorry, and desirous of appeasing the angried translator"

and this gives me the impression that "angried" is an old and rare alternative spelling of "angered". See also [angered vs angried](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=angried%2Cangered&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=1).

Note that the quote you provided is in *italics* and uttered by a child in a novel which points to it not necessarily reflecting standard usage. See [the full quote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbSJt.png), also listed below in my edit.

Conclusion: use it at your own peril.

---

**Edit:**

Since you insist that my assessment of your search link was wrong, let's have a look.

We have a lot of old texts. Examples:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3ytb.png -- a recent book quoting an old
  text
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCg6W.png -- a recent book quoting an old
  text
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNCia.png -- an old text

There were also some contemporary usages. Examples:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbSJt.png -- used by an unruly
  five-year-old, in *italics*
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlmsO.png -- person A uses "angried", B
  corrects her
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8pev.png -- a quote in heavy dialect

Apart from these, there were some results which had in common that they

1. used the word "angried" once in the whole book
2. were published through self-publishing services

For instance:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/4siNO.png -- self-published archaic-sounding poetry in ([link](https://books.google.se/books?id=_jfbBQAAQBAJ))
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/glpMR.png -- self-published youth thriller
  ([link](https://books.google.se/books?id=wSxPAAAAQBAJ))

---

One last thing: let's look at [angried vs soliloquy](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=angried%2Csoliloquy). Note how the rather rare word "soliloquy" is more than 10000 times more common than angried throughout the whole century.

If none of these things convince you, and you insist on these sources being enough for you to use the word "angried", that's completely fine. I would use the common and accepted word "angered" instead.

Comment: Ngram results show its usages even in 2016, 2011, 1999, 1960 etc. Please check the citation link in the question.

Comment: @mahmudkoya I did already adress that, but now I made it even more explicit.

Comment: Instead of reducing a word usage to be a matter of our personal choice, what would you say about its general use in current English, is it appropriate or acceptable in modern and standard English?

Comment: The word is not in common use nor is it listed in any dictionary. It also seems to mean the same thing as a similar but much more common word, which is listed in dictionaries. What more do you want to know?

Answer (score 1):

The [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=angry%2Cangered%2Cangried&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cangry%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cangered%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cangried%3B%2Cc0) shows a small use of 'angered' against 'angry' but zero baseline for 'angried'.

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/7624?redirectedFrom=angried#eid) lists only one reference for 'angried' and it is represented as 'obsolete' with its reference being 'angrieth' not, actually, 'angried.

> 1642   T. Fuller Holy State v. i. 358   Nothing **angrieth** her so much, as when modest men affect a deafnesse.

---

The word 'angered' is listed by the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/7500?rskey=Vzu1HJ&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) without it saying it is 'rare' or 'obsolete' yet it has no modern references for it (surprisingly) :

> 1881   Daily News 11 Aug. 2/2   A somewhat **angered** controversy took place across the table.
>   1883   Harper's Mag. Feb. 483/1   The young man became **angered.**

OED gives the meanings 'irritated, inflamed, flushed with rage'.

Looking at the list linked to in the OP, I suspect that there is a BrE/AmE preference showing up, but it would require a lot of research to prove it.

Comment: No sir, it is not one writer's dim remembering. If you go through my cited link, you will find lots of such usage by different writers.

Comment: Understood. I have looked at the link more closely and edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is whether *angried* can be used in place of *angry* (which isn’t the same as *angered*) in your sample sentence. The other answers deal with the “standard and acceptable usage” part of your question. This answer deals with the portion in your title and in the bulk of your question text: *whether one can be used in place of the other*.

No, there is an important difference.

- No, actually I'm angry.

Being *angry* is purely an internal state. Although the context may indicate that there was a trigger for the anger, the wording doesn’t reference the trigger.

- No, actually I'm angried.

Being *angried* (or *angered*), on the other hand, references the trigger: it isn’t simply that you were angry, but that something made you so.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a misspelling or a nonstandard form at best (as a pp of to anger) Its usage is really rare, see:

> [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%20angried&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cangried%3B%2Cc0): angried
>
> [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=angried%2C%20angry&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cangried%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cangry%3B%2Cc0): angried vs angry